# Does someone knows of a free asmx webhosting?

Tags: asp.net, web-development, web-services, web-hosting

I wrote a webservice (*.asmx) and I want to host it for free.
Couldn't find a website that alows web service hosting.

Does someone know of such ?

Comment: Were you aware that Microsoft considers ASMX to be a "legacy technology"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Appharbor](http://www.appharbor.com) should work well for you.

Answer (score 2):

> Couldn't find a website taht alows web service hosting.

ASMX web services are hosted in ASP.NET applications. So don't look for a hosting provider for web services as such thing doesn't exist, look for a hosting provider of ASP.NET applications. Also ASMX web services are totally deprecated technology now and basing new development on them would be simply put: wrong decision. Their replacement is [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324).

Comment: I tried that also. Didn't find a a good one.

Comment: @Elad Benda, what have you tried? What is your definition of *good one*? What are your requirements, budget, etc, ... In fact you don't need to tell this as your question will become off-topic and get closed. StackOverflow is a programming related Q&A site, so unless you have a specific question about the development process of your web service you should not ask it here. Choosing a hosting provider for your application is considered off-topic for this site.

Comment: You're likely to get either a good web host or a free one. Getting both is pretty unlikely - servers, the Windows stack, bandwidth, staff, etc. all cost money.